# Constructing two independent Bernoulli random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

As I was talking with a friend of mine who is starting probability theory he asked me to construct two independent Bernoulli random variables, he wanted the full construction from the probability spaces.

I gave him the following construction but I made a big mistake:

I define the random variable $X$ on the probability space $\{ \Omega, F, P  \}$

where I take $\Omega = (0,1)$, $F = \{ (0,1), \emptyset, (0, 1/2], (1/2,1) \}$
and $P$ the Lebesgue measure

As $X( (0,1/2]) = 0$ and $X((1/2, 1) = 1$

Now I want to define a random variable $Y$ that has Bernoulli distribution and is independent from the one I have just defined. So what I did was the following:

I defined a new probability space $\{  \Omega_1, F_1, P _1  \}$ where I took  $\Omega_1 = (1/4, 5/4)$, $F_1 = \{ (1/4,5/4), \emptyset, (1/4, 3/4], (3/4,5/4) \}$ and $P_1$ again as the lebesgue measure on $R$.

And I took $Y$ to be $Y((1/4,3/4])= 0$ and $Y((3/4,5/4))= 1$, I then claimed that $Y$ and $X$ where independent because

$$P(Y^{-1}(1) \cap X^{-1}(1)) = P((1/4, 1/2]) = 1/4 = P(Y^{-1}(1)) P (X^{-1}(1)) $$

But I did not continue to check the other cases that obviously came out wrong, now following this construction I would like to give a correct example to my friend but I feel this might be a bit more complicated of what I imagined at the start.

Could someone provide a correct construction maybe taking as the first random variable the random variable $X$ I defined?

Comment: The usual recipe has $Y=0$ on $[0,1/4)\cup[1/2,3/4)$ and $=1$ on the complement.  Think: $X$ is the most significant binary digit of a uniform point in $[0,1]$ and $Y$ is the next most significant binary digit.